# undefined reference but I have installed libical

Tags: c++, c

I am trying to compile and run [cyrus-imapd-2.4.17-caldav-beta9](http://cyrusimap.web.cmu.edu/mediawiki/index.php/Latest_Updates).

This project has a file called configure which creates the makefile.

When I run the makefile I get errors "undefined reference to...".

One of these references is lost libical which I have installed.

In fact I have installed:

```
apt-get install libdb-dev
apt-get install libsasl2-dev
apt-get install  libsnmp-dev
apt-get install libxml2-dev
apt-get install libical-dev
apt-get install libsqlite3-dev
```

I generate makefile as follow:

```
CFLAGS=-I/usr/include/libxml2 ./configure  --enable-murder
```

Run the makefile as follows:

```
CFLAGS=-I/usr/include/libxml2/libxml make
```

Some of the errors:

```
http_caldav.o: In function `is_valid_timerange':
http_caldav.c:(.text+0x3c86): undefined reference to `icaltime_is_valid_time'
http_caldav.c:(.text+0x3cd8): undefined reference to `icaltime_is_valid_time'
http_caldav.c:(.text+0x3d2a): undefined reference to `icaltime_is_date'
http_caldav.c:(.text+0x3d7c): undefined reference to `icaltime_is_date'
http_caldav.c:(.text+0x3dce): undefined reference to `icaltime_is_utc'
http_caldav.c:(.text+0x3e23): undefined reference to `icaltime_is_utc'
http_caldav.o: In function `parse_comp_filter':
http_caldav.c:(.text+0x3e7d): undefined reference to `xmlStrcmp'
http_caldav.c:(.text+0x3e98): undefined reference to `xmlGetProp'
http_caldav.c:(.text+0x3eb7): undefined reference to `xmlStrcmp'
http_caldav.c:(.text+0x3f02): undefined reference to `xmlStrcmp'
http_caldav.c:(.text+0x3f19): undefined reference to `xmlStrcmp'
http_caldav.c:(.text+0x3f46): undefined reference to `xmlStrcmp'
http_caldav.c:(.text+0x3f71): undefined reference to `xmlStrcmp'
http_caldav.o:http_caldav.c:(.text+0x3f9c): more undefined references to `xmlStrcmp' follow
http_caldav.o: In function `parse_comp_filter':
http_caldav.c:(.text+0x4077): undefined reference to `xmlFree'
http_caldav.c:(.text+0x40cc): undefined reference to `xmlStrcmp'
http_caldav.c:(.text+0x40d9): undefined reference to `icaltimezone_get_utc_timezone'
http_caldav.c:(.text+0x410f): undefined reference to `xmlGetProp'
http_caldav.c:(.text+0x412d): undefined reference to `icaltime_from_string'
http_caldav.c:(.text+0x4171): undefined reference to `xmlFree'
http_caldav.c:(.text+0x41a0): undefined reference to `icaltime_from_timet_with_zone'
http_caldav.c:(.text+0x41f2): undefined reference to `xmlGetProp'
http_caldav.c:(.text+0x4210): undefined reference to `icaltime_from_string'
http_caldav.c:(.text+0x4254): undefined reference to `xmlFree'
http_caldav.c:(.text+0x4283): undefined reference to `icaltime_from_timet_with_zone'
```

How could I solve this problem of missing references?,

Thanks.

Comment: Did you tell your compiler to link against `libical`? In GCC (I haven't used that many compilers until now, but I think this is the same with most others) this would be `-lical` _after_ the object/source file which needs to get linked against this lib.

Comment: I'm not used to working with C, but I'm trying to do what you mention me. The make file is autogenerated. I'll try try modifying CFLAGS, but not how to add two references from there. Should point to / usr/include/libical. I'll try to find how.

Comment: @ldav1s This was the post that I started to look for the solution. Here are the installations that I have done.